# How to break text in subsection heading in Beamer using Copenhagen theme?

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Copenhagen} 
\begin{document} 
\title[Title]{} 
\author[Author]{} 
\institute[Test]{} 
\date{\today} 
\subject{Informatics} 
{ \begin{frame} 
\titlepage 
\end{frame} } 
\section{Introduction} 
\subsection{Test subsection with a really long title and some additional words for the example} 
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{Table} 
Test Section 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now as it can bee seen that in 2nd slide the text of subsection does not appear completely and it does not shift to the next, i was having this problem, if anyone can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the optional argument like

```
\subsection[test sub section]{Test subsection with a really long title and 
                              some additional words for the example}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\begin{document}
  \title[Title]{}
  \author[Author]{}
  \institute[Test]{}
  \date{\today}
  \subject{Informatics}
  \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
  \end{frame}
  \section{Introduction}
    \subsection[test sub section]{Test subsection with a really long title 
                                  and some additional words for the example}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table}
      Test Section
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The optional argument is used for running content.

If you want to display the entire title (bad idea IMHO), here is an ugly way:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=4.5ex,dp=2.5ex]{section in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=4.5ex,dp=2.5ex]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}


\begin{document}
  \title[Title]{}
  \author[Author]{}
  \institute[Test]{}
  \date{\today}
  \subject{Informatics}
  \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
  \end{frame}
  \section{Introduction}
    \subsection{\protect\parbox{0.5\linewidth}{Test subsection with a really long title and some additional words for the example}}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table}
      Test Section
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But I want to display the title of whole subsection {Test subsection with a really long title 
                                  and some additional words for the example}

Comment: In this case only the text [test sub section] will be displayed.

Comment: @Ahmed: It will be a bad idea to display big headings in the header. Doesn't look nice.

Comment: Any idea to keep this in a fixed width as given.

Or to break the title in two lines.

I know it doesn't look nice, but its need of the time.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, the height of headline is increase, but it gives extra line spacing which makes the look of slide not that much good.

Comment: @Ahmed I did some update. Please see if it is enough.